# Making StyleSheet Render First?

Tags: css

I have a program that works fine on my development machine and on QA but it does not work properly on Stage.

The issue seems to be that Stage is a much slower box and it takes a long time for the web page to come up.  When it does come up most of the various sections of the page look fine, but there is one section of code that comes up "raw"...but this I mean that the stylesheet has not been applied to it.

Is there a way to "force" this stylesheet to be applied to the page first?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using multiple style sheets or just one?  If you have multiple, it could just be that the styles controlling that section haven't downloaded yet.

Comment: Does doing a reload, skip cache on the page help (Shift-Ctrl-R in Firefox)? Sometimes this happens during my testing too, and I have to force the browser to re-download the CSS.